# Rebuilding OpenCV 3.2.0 - ippicv downloader not found

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm trying to re-build OpenCV 3.2.0. It worked last week but now I can't create a make target. The command I'm using is:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     -D WITH_CUDA=ON     -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1     -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1     -D WITH_CUBLAS=1      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules  ..
```

The error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:243 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:37 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:558 (include)
```

Comment: The error is denoted by "CMake Error" words.

Answer (score 0):

In the directory `/home/nettef/opencv-3.2.0/3rdparty/ippicv/` there was a version of ippicv present, so I just created an empty file called `downloader.cmake` and the error disappeared.